# How do I call to a void method to incorporate it in a method in a different class?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

My assignment is to create a program that simulates a simple online shopping program.
we have to:
create a main menu with 3 options and then a submenu when selecting the 2nd option on the main menu.

I'm unsure how call a method from another class for example:

I have been given a method:

```
public void start() {
```

which is in the file "GroceryStore.java"

I am supposed to create a topMenu method which when the user inputs "1" calls to the method:

```
public void displayItems(){
```

^in file called "Stock.java"

which then prints out an array of items that online store has in stock. The array in the 
Stock.java is

```
private SalesItem[] items;
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I have to do this for several things and I'm hoping I can apply the skeleton of this to the rest of the cases.

Comment: It looks like you already have a framework of your project.  If you can post that, It can give us some useful context.  If you can manage a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), that would be even better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so start() is in the GroceryStore class.

So in a public static void main class you would go :

```
GroceryStore gs = new GroceryStore();
gs.start();
```

In your GroceryStore class you would have a new method which looks like (You may want to have the Stock stock = new Stock() line in the constructor of the GroceryStore object-- would make more sense:

```
Stock stock = new Stock();
public void topMenu(int parm){
   if(parm==1)then{
      stock.displayItems();
   }
}
```

And then finally in the Stock class you have the displayItems method which may look like :

```
public void displayItems(){
  for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
     SalesItem temp = items[i];
     System.out.prinlnt(temp.toString());//or this may be temp.getName() or whatever returns a string from this SalesItem object - I dont know what it looks like - you never said!

  }
}
```

It is however essential you actually understand what is going on here not just copy paste and run?! This wont actually do anything anyway until you have a call to the topMenu method passing it 1, so you will need to workout how you are going to interact with your gs object whether its by keyboard input, mouse click on a gui or something else :)

Comment: Thank you this what I was looking for. It's by a premade keyboard input method the task has given us. I understand all of it apart from why I need to say Stock stock = new Stock();.

Comment: You need that because otherwise the GroceryStore object has no way of calling the displayItems method - as that exists in an instance of the Stock object and not of the GroceryStore object. So we make a new Stock object and call its method :).

If this is your answer please flag it as such using the tick to the top left of my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For now, I'm going to assume that `Stock` is an instance type(it sounds like an instance type), and It would make sense that your `GroceryStore` would have a reference to 1 or more `Stock` items.

---

Your `Stock`s will have to be instantiated with the `new` keyword. so

```
Stock myStock = new Stock(/*parameters for constructor*/);
```

after you do that, you can call the `displayItems` method of `myStock` like so

```
myStock.displayItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

To call a method outside the current instance you have multiple options:

- make the method `static` (so that it won't be attached to any particular instance) and call it through `MyClass.method()`, this has sense if it is a stateless object, mostly an utility method
- create a static instance variable that can be accessed (so method is not static but the specific object is), then call it through `SomeClass.stock.method()`, this has sense when you want a single object of a specific type throughout the program
- create a normal instance variable inside the class from which you want to call the method (this has sense just if the object contained is used in a [HAS-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship). Then you call it simply doing `this.stock.method()` (you can omit `this`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler where to get the methods from if the method is not in the same class. The best way of doing this would be to create an object that refers to the class you're trying to reach (using the `New` Java keyword and the appropriate syntax, i.e. `ClassName objectName = new ClassName()` - you may want to include any parameters you may have).

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776306/java-calling-a-method-from-another-class) other StackOverflow answer - the user had a question very similar to yours, so it may help.

Also, there is a pretty good tutorial on objects and classes on [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm). I suggest you have a look at it and give it a go. Try understanding the concept behind what you're trying to achieve first - I can guarantee you it will help later on as this is a very fundamental concept in OO programming.