# How to call methods from other class?

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to write a Java program to book hotel rooms. I have written methods in one class and am trying to call it from my main class, but I don't know how to do it. 
The program asks the user to input necessary info for the methods, but I just don't know how to execute it. 
I also want to know how to change the status of a room to "B" - for booked, when the user enters the RoomId and confirms their booking and then to print the information using the print() method in Room.java.
 Any help would be great. Thanks
 
**Room.java**

```
package utilities;

public class Room
{

 private String roomId;
 private String description;
 private String status;
 private double dailyRate;
 private DateTime bookingStartDate;
 private DateTime bookingEndDate;

 public Room(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate)
 {
  this.setRoomId(roomId);
  this.setDescription(description);
  this.setDailyRate(dailyRate);
  this.status = "A";
 }

 public boolean bookRoom (String customerID, int nightsRequired)
 {
     if (status.equals('A'))
     {
         System.out.println("You have booked the room");
         status = "B";
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("This room cannot be booked");
         return false;
     }
 }

 public void print()
 {
     System.out.println("Room ID: " + getRoomId());
     System.out.println("Description: "+ getDescription());
     System.out.println("Status: " + status);
     System.out.println("Daily Rate: " + getDailyRate());
     if (status.equals('B'))
     {
         System.out.println(bookingStartDate);
         System.out.println(bookingEndDate);
     }
     else{
     }

 }

/**
 * @return the dailyRate
 */
public double getDailyRate() {
    return dailyRate;
}

/**
 * @param dailyRate the dailyRate to set
 */
public void setDailyRate(double dailyRate) {
    this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
}

/**
 * @return the description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/**
 * @param description the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

/**
 * @return the roomId
 */
public String getRoomId() {
    return roomId;
}

/**
 * @param roomId the roomId to set
 */
}
```

**TestRoom.java**

```
package stuff;

import java.util.Scanner;

import utilities.Room;

public class TestRoom {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     Room [] rooms = 
          {
            new Room("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.00),
            new Room("GARDEN0002", "SouthEast Garden View", 65.0),
            new Room("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35.00),
            new Room("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52.0),
            new Room("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35.00),
            new Room("GARDEN0006", "East Garden View", 35.00)


          };
  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Input a lower price range. ");
  int lower = userInput.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Input an upper price range. ");
  int upper = userInput.nextInt();


  if (lower < 65)
  {
      for ( int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++ )
      {
          if (rooms[i].getDailyRate() > lower && rooms[i].getDailyRate() < upper )
          {    
              System.out.println("ID: \t" + rooms[i].getRoomId() );
              System.out.println("DESC: \t" + rooms[i].getDescription() );
              System.out.println("RATE: \t" + rooms[i].getDailyRate() + "\n");
          }
      }
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("There are no rooms that fit your criteria.");
  }

  System.out.println("Input the ID of the room you wish to book.");
  String roomId = userInput.next();

  System.out.println("Please enter your customer ID");
  String customerID = userInput.next();

  System.out.println("Please enter the amount of nights you wish to stay.");
  int nightsRequired = userInput.nextInt();

  // Code to actually make the booking. I don't know what goes here.
```

Comment: itterrate trough rooms, to find match, or put all rooms into map, which room id will be a key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776306/java-calling-a-method-from-another-class I think this is what u looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Just get the instance of the `Room` and call the method.

The hard-coding method will be like this:

```
Room toBook = null;
for (Room r : rooms) {
    if (r.getRoomId().equals(roomId))
        toBook = r;
}

if (toBook != null) {
    if (toBook.bookRoom(customerID, nightsRequired)) {
         // room booked succesfully
    } else {
         // can't book the room
    }
} else {
    // room does not exists
}
```

But, as long as this will be a bigger app I recommend you to code your [own equals method](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) then `Arrays.contains()` will find the `Room`.

```
Room toBook = new Room(roomid);
if (rooms.contains(toBook) && toBook.bookRoom(customerID, nightsRequired)){
    // room booked succesfully
} else if (rooms.contains(toBook)) {
    // can't book the room
} else {
    // room does not exists
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get that the room doesn't exist.

Comment: my bad, i though `roomId` was an int... **in Java we must compare `String`s always with `equals` not with `==`**... check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Add the code at the end of the main() method in Test class

```
    Room r=null;
    boolean val=false;
    for(int i=0;i<rooms.length;i++){
        if(rooms[i].getRoomId().equals(roomId)){
            r=new Room(rooms[i].getRoomId(), rooms[i].getDescription(), rooms[i].getDailyRate());
            r.bookRoom(customerID, nightsRequired);
            val=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(val){
         r.print();
    }
```