# How to call a function from one class to another in java? And is this constructor method valid?

Tags: java

```
public Account(int initialBalance) {
        balance = initialBalance;
    //Account
}
    // Create method for adding topUp balance   

 public Account tryToTopUp(int balance, int topUpBalance) {
     int newBalance = balance + topUpBalance;
     int balanceAfterTopUp = new currentBalance(newBalance);
     Account currentBalance = new Account(newBalance);
     return currentBalance;

}
```

Comment: Sorry I had to remove the brackets to post the question

Comment: Guessing where your brackets were supposed to be, you need to put mroe detail as to what you need help with. Don't put it in the title, edit this question with the details. Also to the upper right is a help link where you can find information on how to ask a good question. Details are key.

Comment: "Sorry I had to remove the brackets to post the question" not quite. Code-only questions are not allowed here (at lest from new users). Some text describing problem you are facing is also required. So don't skip any important details but [edit] your question with proper code and proper problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you class name is Account then you constructor if fine and i am hoping that you have defined the 'balance' variable at top of class.

If you want to call tryToTopUp method from another class , create object of you Account class in other class

```
Account acc = new Account(100);
acc.tryToTopUp(100, 500);
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776306/java-calling-a-method-from-another-class) will be of some help or [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_method_calling.html)